# Language Fallback / Setting the language in Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.TextByLanguage(key, language);?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I am utilizing the Language Fallback provider.   This does not appear to have any influence on items stored in System > Dictionary.

I would like it to fallback to the language specified in the "Fallback" attribute of the Language item.

Worse case, I would like to fallback to English.

My method for getting text out of the Dictionary can call this.

**Globalization.Translate.TextByLanguage(key, *????*);**

I am stuck on:

1. How do I find the value of the "Fallback" attribute for the currently specified language
2. How do I pass that to TextByLanguage.   It appears to be expecting a Language attribute, but Language doesn't appear to have
   any constructors.

---

HISTORICAL: Following @Jammykam 's advice I took a look at the Verndale example but I am having zero luck with it.   It does not appear to ever fire.

I added the following class to my solution:

```
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Globalization;
using Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation;
using Sitecore.SharedSource.PartialLanguageFallback.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sitecore.Web.Pipelines
{
    public class DictionaryFallback : TryGetFromFallbackDomains
    {
        public static bool EnableFallback
        {
            get
            {
                return Sitecore.Context.Site != null &&
                       Sitecore.Context.Site.SiteInfo.Properties["enableFallback"] != null &&
                       Sitecore.Context.Site.SiteInfo.Properties["enableFallback"].Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Runs the processor.
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The arguments.
        ///             </param>
        public void Process(GetTranslationArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, "args");
            List<string> processedDomains = new List<string>();
            if (args.HasResult || Context.Site == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Site.DictionaryDomain))
                return;
            this.Args = args;
            this.Database = args.Options.Database ?? args.ContentDatabase;
            DictionaryDomain domain;
            if (!DictionaryDomain.TryParse(Context.Site.DictionaryDomain, this.Database, out domain) || domain == null) {
                Log.Info("Error Parsing Dictionary: " + domain.FullyQualifiedName, this);
                return;
            }


            string result;
            if (this.TryGetTranslation(domain, processedDomains, out result) && result != null)
            {
                Log.Info("Normal Translation: " + domain.FullyQualifiedName + ": " + result, this);
                args.Result = result;
            }
            else if (EnableFallback)
            {
                if (this.TryTranslateTextByFallbackLanguage(args, domain, out result) && result != null)
                {
                    Log.Info("Fallback Translation: " + domain.FullyQualifiedName + ": " + result, this);
                    args.Result = result;
                }
            }

        }

        protected virtual bool TryTranslateTextByFallbackLanguage(GetTranslationArgs args, DictionaryDomain domain, out string result)
        {
            result = null;
            List<string> processedDomains = new List<string>();

            // check if the the language passed in with the args has fallback assigned
            // if so, then get that fallback language
            // must try to get the translation based on that language
            var languageFallsBack = args.Language.HasFallbackAssigned(args.ContentDatabase);
            if (languageFallsBack)
            {
                Language fallbackLanguage = args.Language.GetFallbackLanguage(args.ContentDatabase);

                // the following cannot be called from here, because it is an internal method to the Sitecore.Kernel library
                //Translate.TryTranslateTextByLanguage(args.Key, domain, fallbackLanguage, out result, args.Parameters);

                // therefore, we set Args.Language to the fallbacklanguage
                // this.Args is the Args object in TryGetFromFallbackDomains processor
                // then we call this.TryGetTranslation, which is a method in the TryGetFromFallbackDomains processor, 
                // which IS in the Sitecore.Kernel library and therefore can make the call to TryTranslateTextByLanguage

                this.Args.Language = fallbackLanguage;

                if (this.TryGetTranslation(domain, processedDomains, out result) && result != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // if no results if found, try to see if this fallback language falls back itself to another language
                    // and then if so, try the translation with that
                    // pass into the recursive call this.Args (instead of args), since the language has been updated in this.Args
                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        var isSuccess = TryTranslateTextByFallbackLanguage(this.Args, domain, out result);
                        return isSuccess;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

I added the following code to my patch file:

```
<pipelines>
            <getTranslation>
                <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromCoreDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.Web.Pipelines.DictionaryFallback, Sitecore.Web" />
            </getTranslation>
        </pipelines>
```

I can see it using showconfig.aspx:

```
<getTranslation>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.ResolveContentDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromDomain, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromFallbackDomains, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromSiteDomain, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromContextDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetTranslation.TryGetFromCoreDatabase, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Web.Pipelines.DictionaryFallback, Sitecore.Web" patch:source="SitecoreSettings.config"/>
</getTranslation>
```

You will see in my class that I threw in some logging, but I never see an item logged.   Items that have a version in the selected language render correctly.  But if they don't have a version it's displaying the key instead of falling back.

---

Here is the  section as displayed via showconfig.aspx (my real domain changed here to example.com):

```
<sites><site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="15MB" viewStateCacheSize="1MB" xslCacheSize="25MB" disableBrowserCaching="true" itemwebapi.mode="StandardSecurity" itemwebapi.access="ReadWrite" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" /><site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" /><site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" /><site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" /><site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" /><site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" /><!-- ITEM WEB API SETTINGS FOR A SITE
           Supported attributes (first is default):
             itemwebapi.mode: [Off|StandardSecurity|AdvancedSecurity]
               If set to Off, Item Web API is turned off.
               If set to StandardSecurity, Item Web API is turned on. Default Sitecore security model is used.
               If set to AdvancedSecurity, Item Web API is turned on. Default Sitecore security model is extended with a requirement to explicitely set the 'remote:fieldread' access right for content fields.
             itemwebapi.access: [ReadOnly|ReadWrite]
               If set to ReadOnly, then only READ operation is allowed.
               If set to ReadWrite, then CREATE, READ, UPDATE, and DELETE operations are allowed.
             itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess: [false|true].
               Defines if access is allowed for non-authenticated user.
      --><!--<site name="mysite" patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            virtualFolder="/"
            physicalFolder="/"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content"
            startItem="/home"
            database="web"
            domain="extranet"
            allowDebug="true"
            cacheHtml="true"
            htmlCacheSize="50MB"
            enablePreview="true"
            enableWebEdit="true"
            enableDebugger="true"
            disableClientData="false"/>--><site name="english" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="stage.example.com|127.0.0.1|localhost" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="1GB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="chinese" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="chinesestage.example.com" language="zh-CN" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="german" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="germanstage.example.com" language="de-DE" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="spanish" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="spanishstage.example.com" language="es-ES" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="french" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="frenchstage.example.com" language="fr-FR" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="italian" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="italianstage.example.com" language="it-IT" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="japanese" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="japanesestage.example.com" language="ja-JP" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="portuguese" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="portuguesestage.example.com" language="pt-BR" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="russian" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" hostName="russianstage.example.com" language="ru-RU" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="500MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" enableFallback="true" patch:source="SiteDefinition.config" /><site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" itemwebapi.mode="Off" itemwebapi.access="ReadOnly" itemwebapi.allowanonymousaccess="false" htmlCacheSize="1GB" /><site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" /><site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" /><site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" /></sites>
```

---

**CLOSING UPDATE:** I used the accepted answer below and modified it to work for me: https://gist.github.com/eat-sleep-code/0ea3f1bd2be19bbf9fc6

Comment: Did you set 'enableFallback=true' on your <site> node in config?

Comment: @jammykam Yes.   I added that sections output from showconfig.aspx above.

Comment: That all looks correct to me. Try moving your processor higher up/first and check if it is running correct.

Comment: I added some more logging lines.   It appears that Context.Site.DictionaryDomain is an empty string?   This causes the Process to exit.   How to I resolve that?

Comment: @jammykam the Gist you sent has an undefined variable called "database" I tried this.Database in it's place and well it wasn't happy about that.   I tried using nothing, and again it wasn't happy.

Comment: It's untested unfortunately since I don't currently have a solution to be able to test it on. If you're not using domain dictionary then the other solution will work fine, you should use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already solved this before, Please check the following blog post, the section related to dictionary items:

[Dictionary Items Language Fallback](http://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.com/2015/08/dictionary-items-langauge-fallback.html)

I also built a module for this, uploaded to sitecore still waiting review.

Comment: I can see a couple of issues in your code. Since you have hardcoded the dictionary item ID it will not work with dictionary domains. There is also no recursive call for fallback of fallbacks.

Comment: That was the solution I needed, I just need one level  of fallback else the key of the dictionry items will br retrieved

Comment: The last updated code check for the context domain "extranet" which is the domain that I want my code to work on , any ideas or additions would be great

Comment: Sure, it's just an observation. Dictionary domains are different to security domains, it allows you to specify a different dictionary per website in multisite implementations (http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/11/sitecore-aspnet-cms-6-6-features-dictionary-domains.aspx)

Comment: @jammykam Thanks for this but I think the code exist in the blog with a little tweeks will solve the problem of the question.What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it may well solve the problem right now as it is, but with those tweeks it will cover more use cases.

Comment: I got this working using @MohammedSyam solution although I had to make several changes.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary items do not work with the language fallback module by default, you have to patch the getTranslate pipeline with an additional processor to make the fallback language check and get the correct dictionary item in the fallback language.

You can find additional details in this article about [Using Fallback with the Dictionary](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/elizabeth-spranzani/posts/2014/03/fallback-series-post-5.aspx), after which you can continue to use the dictionary as normal without having to pass through the language with `Globalization.Translate.TextByLanguage(key)`.

Comment: I tried that.   The code does not successfully build -- even after fixing the broken references.   My Sitecore.Kernel.dll is from Sitecore 8.   I am not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: The only part of the code you need is `TryGetFromFallbackLanguage.cs` and the addition to the getTranslate pipeline config. Add those into your  own solution and try rebuilding. There appears to be other parts of the code which refer to out dated libraries (search contrib) which are no longer valid in Sitecore 7+.

Comment: Silly question... what is the syntax I would use within a view to get the text from the dictionary using this method?

Comment: At the top of your page `@using Sitecore.Globalization` and then to retrieve the dictionary use `@Translate.Text("key")`

Comment: @eat-sleep-code The code is expecting a dictionaryDomain attribute on your sites node. Try this Process method instead, I added fallback: https://gist.github.com/jammykam/ac3a8919565e9902a0d2